# Поддерживает ли qiwi api автовыплаты на другие кошельки по запросу?

Tags: qiwi

Подскажите, поддерживает ли qiwi api автовыплаты (автопереводы, если хотите) на другие кошельки по запросу ? Т.е. есть кнопка вывода средств при нажатию на которую я ввожу номер и на этот номер осуществляется вывод Нной суммы..

Comment: Уточните, вам нужен перевод средств с одного Qiwi-кошелька на другой Qiwi-кошелёк без непосредственного участия человека (кроме ввода номера)?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен после детального изучения документации. Делюсь кодом ниже. Curl можно сократить, брал просто из другого своего обработчика )

```
$url = 'https://edge.qiwi.com/sinap/api/v2/terms/99/payments';
$data= array(
    "id"=>"TEST123", //Любой идентификатор, генерируемый у вас на сервере
    "sum"=>[
        "amount"=>2.25, //Сумма перевода
        "currency"=>"643" 
        ],
    "paymentMethod"=>[
        "type"=>"Account",
        "accountId"=>"643"
        ],
    "comment"=>"test",
    "fields"=>[
        "account"=>"НОМЕР КОМУ ПЕРЕВОДИМ" //Номер получателя в международнем формате +7
        ]

    );
$data= json_encode($data); 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ("Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ТОКЕН"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
$output  = curl_exec ($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

Кастомизируйте под себя, кому надо..экранизация, проверки на POST, сумму, и т.п.